# dlib cannot be installed in Vscode. what i have to do?

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install `dlib` library but it is failing!

```
(base) C:\Users\ruivi\Desktop\dk>pip install dlib

Collecting dlib
  Using cached dlib-19.22.0.tar.gz (7.4 MB)
Building wheels for collected packages: dlib
  Building wheel for dlib (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\ruivi\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ruivi\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-b_ver4tk\\dlib_f6c779cab69741ccb4182341ca223bf0\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ruivi\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-b_ver4tk\\dlib_f6c779cab69741ccb4182341ca223bf0\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\ruivi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-enh6rzgt'
       cwd: C:\Users\ruivi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-b_ver4tk\dlib_f6c779cab69741ccb4182341ca223bf0\
  Complete output (326 lines):

............skip(because of exeeding 30000 charactor).....................


ERROR: Failed building wheel for dlib
```

Comment: Please mention `python` version of your base environment

Comment: 3.6 is the viersion